# How to stop the music playing in background in android

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, background-music

i tried to stream an audio from url and its working fine. The url is playing on background also when i quit the application. But i cant able to stop it when i enter my app again how could i stop. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your main activity (or wherever you placed your player):

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Put your media player object here
    mp.pause();
}
```

That should stop your music whenever you leave your activity.

Comment: @ sander i know this pause method ...what i asked is the music is playing in background when resume my application again after my exit i cant able to stop with stop button....As how android music player does...?

Comment: onPause is not called when HOME button is pressed. One should use onUserLeaveHint() for that case.

Answer (score 0):

In your onBackPressed method write mp.stop() and then mp=null where mp is your mediaplayer instance...